# Real Time Calculation (2)?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I recently posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32101290/real-time-calculations)

The answerers did a really good job, but now I am trying to add something to my code and it does not work, I've done all possible debugging but it just won't show the total!
Here is my HTML

```
<label for ="FIELD7">Would you like Weapons?:  </label>
        <label for="FIELD7">Yes</label>
        <input type="radio"  id="weaponyes" name="FIELD7" value="Yes" onclick="doMath()" checked  data-clicked="no" />
        <label for="FIELD7">No</label>
        <input type="radio" id ="weaponno" name="FIELD7" value="No" />
```

Here is my jQuery

```
            function doMath() {
            var basePrice = 15;

            var baseModel = 0;
            var customModel = 5;
            var modelTotal;
            if (document.querySelector('input[name="FIELD6"]:checked').value == "Normal Model") {
                modelTotal = basePrice;
            }
            if (document.querySelector('input[name="FIELD6"]:checked').value == "Workshop Model") {
                modelTotal = customModel;
            }

            var weaponTotal;
            var weapons = 5;
            if(document.querySelector('input[name="FIELD7"]:checked').value == "Yes") {
                weaponTotal = weapons;
            }
            else(document.querySelector('input[name="FIELD7"]:checked').value == "No") {
                weaponTotal = 0;
            }
            var totalPrice = modelTotal + weaponTotal;
            console.log(totalPrice);
            document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = '<span style="color:black">Total Price:' + totalPrice + '</span>';
        }
    </script>
```

I've got the model part figured out, I just need help with where "var weaponTotal;" starts. It won't show the price anymore :(

Comment: so what debugging did you do? `console.log(weapons)`? `console.log(modelTotal)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error.

Use "else if" instead of "else"

```
else if(document.querySelector('input[name="FIELD7"]:checked').value == "No")
```

JS:

```
function doMath() {
    var basePrice = 15;

    var baseModel = 0;
    var customModel = 5;
    var modelTotal;
    if (document.querySelector('input[name="FIELD6"]:checked').value == "Normal Model") {
        modelTotal = basePrice;
    }
    if (document.querySelector('input[name="FIELD6"]:checked').value == "Workshop Model") {
        modelTotal = customModel;
    }

    var weaponTotal;
    var weapons = 5;
    if(document.querySelector('input[name="FIELD7"]:checked').value == "Yes") {
        weaponTotal = weapons;
    }
    else if(document.querySelector('input[name="FIELD7"]:checked').value == "No") {
        weaponTotal = 0;
    }
    var totalPrice = modelTotal + weaponTotal;
    console.log(totalPrice);
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = '<span style="color:black">Total Price:' + totalPrice + '</span>';
}
```